# Terraform Version locking

Tags: terraform

My Apologies if this is a repeat question.  I want to lock down the terraform required version at a global level so that no one in my team can create another resource using a different terraform version.
terraform {
required_version = "1.0.2". ---> I want to lock this.

My repo is the conventional structure - TF_ROOT_DIR/env, env/stage, env/prod TF_ROOT_DIR/global, F_ROOT_DIR/modules

Is it **only** possible to do so in modules using a versions.tf?

Comment: You can set this in the fewest number of places by only doing it in the root module configs. Also, if this is TF Cloud or TFE, you can set the version in the web UI for the runners per-workspace (not the CLI workspace).

Comment: @MattSchuchar Thanks for your response. This is not TF Cloud or TFE, Jut to make sure I understood you correctly the only place is indeed inside the modules i.e. in my case TF_ROOT_DIR/modules/sample-module/versions.tf or any file

Comment: Inside any config in the root module or declared modules.

Comment: @5377037 Thank you for your response, I am a newbie here and thought my question is pretty detailed and self explanatory but i was wrong. Will take care.